# How to show the user that no more records available

Tags: android

I have an Activity with TextView and Image. 
When the user swipes left/right they go to next/previous record. 
Everything works fine but when the user reaches last or first record I want to be able to show some kind of indicator, that there are no more records. Is there a standard way of doing it?

I am using the GestureDetector and the ViewFlipper. See code below.

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    ...
    myDetector = new GestureDetector(this, this);

    findViewById(R.id.scrollView).setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
            return !myDetector.onTouchEvent(event);
        }
    });
    ...
}

@Override
public boolean onFling(MotionEvent e1, MotionEvent e2, float velocityX, float velocityY) {
    if (e1.getRawX() > e2.getRawX()) {
        Log.d("LIF", "Show Next");
        switcher.setInAnimation(this,  R.anim.in_from_right);
        switcher.setOutAnimation(this, R.anim.out_to_left);

        if (nextMessage(message.getId())) {
            switcher.showNext();
        }
    } else {
        Log.d("LIF", "Show Previous");
        switcher.setInAnimation(this, R.anim.in_from_left);
        switcher.setOutAnimation(this, R.anim.out_to_right);

        if (prevMessage(message.getId())) {
            switcher.showPrevious();
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

Comment: You have so many options, but I would say the closest thing to a "standard" is the rebound effect, à la ListViews and the Home Screen. You might also consider displaying a slim View of a contrasting color, e.g. bright red, horizontally on the side of the screen.

Comment: @MikeM. Can you point me to documentation?

Comment: Sorry, I've not done anything with it before. I'm sure a quick Google search will give you many, many results. Or, wait and see if somebody will help you out (if this question doesn't get zapped for being too broad or asking for opinions, that is).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you should consider [ViewPager](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/view/ViewPager.html) instead of the ViewFlipper. View pager has the the overlay indication (like in ListView) out of the box.